# FindGameObjectWithTag seemingly not working for my C# Unity Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get my script, which is used for my enemy AI, to find my players transform but I keep getting the error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
AiChasePlayerState.Update (AiAgent agent) (at Assets/AiChasePlayerState.cs:36)
AiStateMachine.Update () (at Assets/AiStateMachine.cs:33)
AiAgent.Update () (at Assets/AiAgent.cs:25)
```

The following is my script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class AiChasePlayerState : AiState
{
    public Transform playerTransform;
    float timer = 0.0f;
    Animator animator;
    
    public AiStateId GetId()
    {
        return AiStateId.ChasePlayer;
    }
    public void Enter(AiAgent agent)
    {
        if (playerTransform == null)
        {
            playerTransform = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
        }
    }
    public void Update(AiAgent agent)
    {
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (timer < 0.0f)
        {
            float sqDistance = (playerTransform.position - agent.navMeshAgent.destination).sqrMagnitude;
            if (sqDistance > agent.config.maxDistance * agent.config.maxDistance)
            {
                agent.navMeshAgent.destination = playerTransform.position;
            }
            timer = agent.config.maxTime;
        }
        agent.navMeshAgent.destination = playerTransform.position;
        animator.SetFloat("Speed", agent.navMeshAgent.velocity.magnitude);
    }
    public void Exit(AiAgent agent)
    {

    }
}
```

I have tagged my player with the tag "Player" so I don't know why this is happening.
Please help me, thank you.

I tried following the youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1H9jrKyWKs0&t=610s&ab_channel=TheKiwiCoder but I got lost because the guy updated his code without addressing it.

Comment: what line causes problems? error code line numbers are definitely not the same as in your IDE. also, are you sure that your `Enter` method was called?

Comment: I'm assuming the 'public Transform playerTransform;' line is the one causing problems because the error says Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I don't think the 'Enter' method is ever called because I tried using a debug but nothing pops up on console.

Comment: Actually line 36 seems to be `animator.SetFloat("Speed", agent.navMeshAgent.velocity.magnitude);` suggesting either agent  one of its properties is null.. but hey, thats whats debugging is for.  Hence why you should indicate on your code here, the line matching (in case you trimmed things) ..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You were right BugFinder, I feel like a fool.